# onClick addClass color to navbar item - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, addclass

I am trying to make a navbar out of text that hides/shows different divs.  I want to have it so when you click on one of the options, the text turns red to show that it's been selected, and whatever other item is selected is "unselected".  I am fairly new to JavaScript, but I thought the best way to do this is to add a class to it onClick, and remove the class from its siblings onClick.  But it's not working—nothing happens onClick.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head><title>test</title>
<style>
 .reddish { color:red; }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function redFunction() {
$( '.navItem' ).addClass( 'reddish' );
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p class="navItem" onClick="redFunction()">Option 1</p>
<p class="navItem" onClick="redFunction()">Option 2</p>
<p class="navItem" onClick="redFunction()">Option 3</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is it not working? What is your expected result and what is your actual result?

Answer (score 4):

Javascript code should be seperated from css !

```
<style> 
      .reddish { color:red; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function redFunction() { $( "p" ).addClass( 'reddish' ); }
</script>
```

Comment: Fixed, that was stupid of me.  Doesn't solve the problem though.

Comment: Well, .navItem selector should be in quotes : $('.navItem').addClass( 'reddish' );